# Table Sort Plugin Incorrect Record Count

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, jquery-pagination

I am having the following code to load the data in the tablesorter plugin. Here I am showing the number of records in the pgl, but the total count is showing incorrectly when I click 50 and come back to 25.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
<div class="rowsPerPage">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(25);">25</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(50);">50</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(toalnoofrecords);">All</a>
</div>
 <div id="pg">
  <div id="pgl"></div>
  <div id="pgR"></div>
 </div>      


<table id="testtable">
   datas comes here
</table>

<!---- javascript function -->
 function test1(val)
 { 
    $(jQuery('#testtable').tablesorterPager({container: $("#pgR"), positionFixed: false,size: value }));

  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `test1()`? Also, `$( jQuery('#testtable')... )` is an odd format, you don't need to wrap the entire thing in a `$( )`. And another also, `val` and `value` don't match inside of your `test()` function.

Comment: @Mottie Sorry I put test()  instead of test1.Please take a look at now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the original tablesorter plugin (v2.0.5), then use the following code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/380/)):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#testtable')
    .tablesorter()
    .tablesorterPager({
        container: $("#pgR"),
        positionFixed: false,
        size: 10
    });
});

function test(val){
    $t = jQuery('#testtable');
    $t[0].config.size = val;
    $t.trigger('appendCache');
}
```

- Note: that the original tablesorter won't work with jQuery 1.9+ because it uses `$.browser.msie`.

---

If using my [forked version of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/), then use this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/150/)):

HTML

```
<div class="rowsPerPage">
  <a href="#">10</a>
  <a href="#">20</a>
  <a href="#">All</a>
</div>
<div id="pg">
  <div id="pgl"></div>
  <div id="pgR"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#testtable')
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
    })
    .tablesorterPager({
        container: $("#pgR"),
        size: 10
    });

    $('.rowsPerPage a').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).text();
        if (/all/i.test(val)) {
            val = 99999; // pick some huge number
        }
        $('#testtable').trigger('pageSize', val);
        return false;
    });

});
```

- Note: this code uses [unobstrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) , allowing you to easily add more page sizes without including more inline javascript.